# Count how many exist in a one-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a query in which I need to add a column with the tasks name that contains the amount of many that exists in a one-to-many relationship

This is the query I have

```
SELECT 
    e.full_name AS fullName,
    t.issue AS issue,
    CASE t.state
        WHEN 'open' THEN 'open'
        WHEN 'pending' THEN 'In progress'
        WHEN 'closed' THEN 'closed'
    END AS status,
    CASE t.scheduled
        WHEN TRUE THEN 'scheduled'
        WHEN FALSE THEN 'non-scheduled'
    END AS scheduled,
    d.name AS device,
    DATE(t.date_created) AS dateCreated,
    DATE(t.last_updated) AS lastUpdate
FROM
    tickets t
        INNER JOIN
    employees e ON t.employee_id = e.id
        INNER JOIN
    devices d ON d.id = t.device_id
WHERE
    MONTHNAME(t.date_created) = 'August'
ORDER BY dateCreated DESC
```

And this is the scheme in which I work http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39bf3e/1

I try to add *counts* and *group by* but at this point I'm guessing

I am expecting a result that looks like this

[image]

Thanks for any help

Comment: what is you expected output with that schema?

Comment: I expect another column with the name _tasks_ that shows the amount of tasks associated with each ticket

Comment: A sample table with the expected output help a lot to understand on what direction we should go and save us a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks Juan I am working on it now

Comment: Just edit the question and I show an image with the result that I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a derived table like so:

```
SELECT ...
       TotalTasks --Add the count column to your select
FROM ticket t
JOIN (SELECT ticked_id, COUNT(1) as TotalTasks
      FROM tasks
      GROUP BY ticked_id) ta ON t.id = ta.ticked_id
...rest of query
```

Here is your [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39bf3e/19/0) with the entire query

The concept here is to do your aggregation on the *many* table, before joining back to the *one* table.  This ensures a 1-1 join and best prevents unwanted duplication.

Comment: Thanks for answering Aaron, I need a response that lists the tickets without tasks, Adding LEFT JOIN seems to produce the result I expect

Comment: To your query adding LEFT JOIN and IFNULL I am getting the result I want here is the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39bf3e/22

Comment: If this answer your question remember to mark it as accepted so everyone know is already solved.

Comment: @user615274 Glad you were able to adjust it to work.  I wasn't sure which join type you would need when I wrote it, but I wanted to provide the concept.  Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

left join the 2 table and count at the same time that is the basic of finding how many entries are in a one-many relationship